# .contains("@") not working for validating email format in Java

Tags: java, validation, email, format

I'm typing up a program for school that has a list of students including their email address. Part of the program needs to print out invalid email addresses. I've been using the .contains() method but it only seems to partially work.

```
public static void print_invalid_emails()
{
    for(Student s : mStudents)
        {
        if(s.getEmailAddress().contains("@") && s.getEmailAddress().contains(".") && !s.getEmailAddress().contains(" "))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(s.getEmailAddress());
        }

        }   
    }
```

When checking the following email addresses:

John1989@gmail.com

Erickson_1990@gmailcom

The_lawyer99yahoo.com

Erin.black@comcast.net

it only prints Erickson_1990@gmailcom but not The_lawyer99yahoo.com.

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me (in the order you've listed, `true`, `false`, `false`, `true`). Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Actually just figured out what the issue was. another part of the program was removing "The_lawyer99yahoo.com" before it was getting to the email validation section. The code was working fine, just what I was expecting wasn't there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work okay for me.

In another  way you can use this function for validate email id.
Try it

```
 public static boolean validateEmail(String email) {

        String email_pattern
                = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(email_pattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return (matcher.matches());

    }
```

This function returns `true` if the email is valid else return `false`